# Integrate function with more than one variable

Tags: r, integration

I want to integrate a function with respect to the variable *a* in the function stated below.

```
> f <- function(a,b) {a^2 + a*b^2}
> integrate(f(a),lower =0, upper =1)
Error in f(a) : object 'a' not found
```

This is apparently not the right way to do it. I tried other things like `f[a]` instead of `f(a)` and also searched for solutions, but it did not help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to pass the name of the function with its argument in it, R is looking for the object `a` and can't find it. You also need to provide a value for `b`. This works:

```
f <- function(a,b) {a^2 + a*b^2}
integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = 1, b = 5)
```